# Three js shader, how to use alpha map texture with opacity and gradient

Tags: three.js

Need help to make opacity work on shader with gradient and alpha map texture.
With code below results are next: gradient is working but opacity is not.

[image]

This is my alpha texture
[image]

and this is a geometry and material

```
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(32, 32);
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

uniforms: {
 transparent: true,
 alphaMap: { value: alphaTexture },
 color1: {
  value: new THREE.Color("purple")
 },
 color2: {
  value: new THREE.Color("red")
 }
},
vertexShader: `
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
`,
fragmentShader: `
uniform vec3 color1;
uniform vec3 color2;
uniform sampler2D alphaMap;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  float alpha = texture2D(alphaMap, vUv).r;
  vec3 color = mix(color1, color2, vUv.y);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, alpha);
}
`,
});
```

as you can see, the black part of the texture is becoming white, but has to be transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `transparent: true` property is outside your `uniforms` object:

```js
uniforms: {
 // alphamap, color1, color2
},
transparent: true,
```